# Xcode 6 Missing Utility Application Template

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently using Creating iOS Apps: Second Edition by Richard Warren to learn how to make iOS apps. I have Xcode 6, and the book is asking me to set up a Utility Application, but the template does not exist anymore apparently. Is there anything like this template, or is there a way to get the template from somewhere else? Any help is appreciated. If more info is needed, I will gladly provide. Thank you.

Comment: OS X -> Application -> Command Line Tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many templates were removed in Xcode 6. I would start with the Single View Application instead.

Comment: Thank you much, I will try that when I get the chance :)

Comment: This one was close enough, still not perfect, but it'll have to do. Thank you